# How to check if images in an android app are current?

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, auto-update

I am in the middle of writing an android app while teaching myself java all at the same time and my project is a bit cumbersome for a first time app.  NOTE: 
 I am not a newbie to programming, I know several languages with the exception of java and writing code for mobile devices.  With this all said and done, I don't want to have to force my users to have to update the app every time there is a new image.

Is there a way, I am assuming there is, to check on startup if all the images are up to date and if not download the new ones to the drawable resource folder for use in the app?

I have searched and found ways to remotely fetch items but nothing specifically for updating app images.  For example:  Splash Screen Image, or background image etc.

Thanks for your time and apologize if this does not conform to stackoverflow form of asking a question.
Shawn Mulligan

Comment: Why not keep the images on S3 or somewhere on server and use the URL to display the  splash or background image using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) etc.? They do the client side caching as well.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledges, there is no way to do why you're asking for. Resources are static contents and there no way to modify or update them programatically.

To achieve a kind of feature that you describe, it should be through a distant server, eventually with a local cache of your images on disc, associate to a download date.
But you won't be able to use them in the exact same way that you can use drawable resources.

Also depends of what you really mean by "if images are up to date".

Comment: Let's say we are writing a space invader type game, which we are not, this is just the easiest way of explaining it.  We come out with a basic set of invaders that mimic the original ones minus the animation.  6 months down the road we decide to bring them a little up to date.  What we would want is our original images stored somewhere remotely where the app checks to see if the images are the same or not.  Then when we do an update to those images and it checks to see that they are different, it automatically downloads the new images.

Comment: In this case I'll recommend you to update your app with new graphics. (it's not trolling, it's really what I would do).

Comment: I have an imageview and currently 10 different images that load into it depending on what the user chooses.  Them 10 different images will change periodically and regularly.  So would it be better to have the app preload the default image and then remotely grab the other 9 when they are needed?  I just thought there was a way to download and overwrite the old content.  I want it to be as unobtrusive as possible.  Thanks Shawn

Comment: Your need is in fact quite specific, generally people just need remote image fetching with cache and use tools like Glide. So I think you need a default image in the app like you said, then have a remote service (could use Firebase or a standard ws/json) that will return ids and urls of your 9 currents available images. Download those images in disc local storage only if you dont have already done it, delete the ones that are no more available. You have to develop a sync images tools, I dont see how you could avoid it.

Comment: Okay I didn't want to go into specifics but this is the concept, which is part of the app but not the whole app.  I have 9 different prize wheels, each wheel has different prizes on it and different amount of sectors.  Example wheel 1 has 2 sectors, wheel 9 has 10 different sectors on it.  I want to change the wheels from time to time to remove prizes and add new ones to it.  Currently I am using an imageview to do this and the animation etc, which all works fine.  I am searching for an unobtrusive way to change the prize wheels without making the user update the app every time. Thanks Shawn